# Clarification of CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm confused with the query as some people saying that is creates the external table based on the data which is located in external source called `D365` with the path equals to `Location`.

And I think that I creates external table based on the table or view by accessing to `dbo.PurchTable` and then offloads this external table in source called `D365` with the path equal to `Location`.

Could someone please confirm?

```
     CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE parquet.__PurchTable
     WITH 
     (
        LOCATION = ''snapshot/PurchTable/202203'',                                      
        DATA_SOURCE = D365,                                   
        FILE_FORMAT = _parquet
     ) AS SELECT {NameList} FROM  dbo.PurchTable
```

Comment: Is the documentation not clear?

Comment: If you have any business with or interest in external tables, it would be easier to establish this experimentally by trying it rather than asking, as you're not going to be able to successfully work with them without a correct mental model of how things work anyway.